# How to prevent conversion of apostrophe to quotation mark?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I knit the following code to HTML,

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "1/8/2022"
output: html_document
---

'
```

The U+0027 apostrophe (') turns into a U+2019 right single quotation mark (’).

How can I prevent this behavior?

I am using RStudio 2021.09.0 Build 351 and R version 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\`

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "1/8/2022"
output: html_document
---

\'
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Any way to do this for the whole document?

Comment: No sorry. I don't know how to apply it throughout the whole document. I would use it each time I need.

Comment: R studio has find replace tool